# How do I use Type K Thermocouple?

Tags: sensor, temperature, pid-controller, thermocouple

I see a lot of applications using this type of couple but there is no document showing how to proper use it!
In my case I have a 10mm thick steel plate that get heated on one side, should a M6 hole 7mm long be enough for a M6 thermocouple like the one in the image to give proper temperature readings?
Is the end part of the thermocouple the sensor?
[image]

Comment: I suspect that doing some experiments (actual measurements) could be very useful, given your current state.

Comment: Have you read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermocouple ? Why would you even need a document ? Think about what would make sense.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is off-topic for this site: *Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design.*

Comment: As always contact the manufacturer, and read the datasheet. But a thermocouple is so simple you don't need to, there are plenty of resources available to help you use thermocouples on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of thermocouple won't really be ideal. You would like to see an immersion depth of 10x the hole diameter or 60mm for best accuracy.

The sensitive bit is the knob at the end:

[image]

You would like that to press reasonably hard against the bottom of a blind hole so the hole depth should be a bit short of having it go all the way in.

I suggest drilling the hole in from the edge if possible (rather than on the top or bottom) to get the maximum thermal coupling. Running the wires along the plate a bit will also improve the accuracy.